# Multiple GET actions on OData controller results in 404 exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have just begun with writing OData services, and till now I have made good progress. I am trying to add two more GET methods in my controller but the problem is that whenever I try to do that I end up getting the following error message

**ODataURL:**http://localhost:65321/odata/Qualifications/Default.DisplayDoubleValue

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type WebApplication1.Controllers.QualificationsController\r\nDisplayDoubleValue on type WebApplication1.Controllers.QualificationsController",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

I looked into some of the StackOverflow posts and tried to follow the same but the only way I am able to call my custom methods are if I have only one `HTTPGet attribute` in my controller

### Given are the get methods of my Qualification controller

```
// GET: odata/Qualifications
    [HttpGet]
   [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Qualification> Get()
    {
        return db.Qualifications;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public double DisplayDoubleValue()
    {
        return 12.0;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string HelloName([FromODataUri] string name)
    {
        return "Hello" + name;
    }
```

### Given is the Web.config file in my App_Start folder

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Qualification>("Qualifications");

        //custom function configure 1
        var customFunctionGetHelloName = builder.EntityType<Qualification>().Collection.Function("HelloName");
        customFunctionGetHelloName.Parameter<string>("name");
        customFunctionGetHelloName.Returns<string>();

        //custom function configure 2
        var customFunctionGetDisplayDoubleVal = builder.EntityType<Qualification>().Collection.Function("DisplayDoubleValue");
        customFunctionGetDisplayDoubleVal.Returns<double>();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
                        name: "DefaultApiByAction",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
                      name: "DefaultApiByActionId",
                      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                  );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( //MapHTTPRoute for controllers inheriting ApiController
                           name: "DefaultApi",
                           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                       );
    }
```

As mentioned in some of the other posts I have added the following in my web.config file to avoid IIS routing problems but doing that too does not help

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules >
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />  
  </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

And my OData metadata shows me that it has two action methods which I can call but I guess I am making a mess somewhere in the routing which I am not able to figure out

```
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Default">
<Function Name="HelloName" IsBound="true">
<Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(WebApplication1.Models.Qualification)"/>
<Parameter Name="name" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="false"/>
<ReturnType Type="Edm.String" Unicode="false"/>
</Function>
<Function Name="DisplayDoubleValue" IsBound="true">
<Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(WebApplication1.Models.Qualification)"/>
<ReturnType Type="Edm.Double" Nullable="false"/>
</Function>
```

Please let me know where I am making a mess is it the routing or some attribute I need to add in the controller to make it work.

Comment: Just wondering if in the routing where ID is optional on the first two, if no ID is sent how does the routing work? DefaultApiByAction, and DefaultApiByActionID would then be the confusion perhaps?

Comment: @JohnPeters even if i remove that the case remains the same config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                          name: "DefaultApiByActionId",
                          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}" );
I tried to remove the id part from the template and still when i try to access my custom get i still face the same error message